# Understanding Comonad's <$$>

Tags: haskell, comonad

Given the following from [fp-course](https://github.com/data61/fp-course):

```
class Functor f where
  (<$>) ::
    (a -> b)
    -> f a
    -> f b

class Functor f => Extend f where
  (<<=) ::
    (f a -> b)
    -> f a
    -> f b
```

I defined `<$$>` as so:

```
(<$$>) ::
  Comonad f =>
  (a -> b)
  -> f a
  -> f b
(<$$>) f fa = f <$> fa
```

However, I'm interested to know if there's another way to implement `<$$>` without using `<$>`. Is there? If so, please show it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the `extract` method of `Comonad`; `Extend` isn't enough to get away without `fmap`.

```
(<$$>)
  :: Comonad f
  => (a -> b)
  -> f a
  -> f b
f <$$> w = f . extract <<= w
```

This is basically how `liftW` is implemented in `Control.Comonad`.

Note also that you need `<<=` (or `extend`); `extract` and `duplicate` aren't sufficient. The situation is similar to that of `Bind` and `Monad`; you can implement `fmap` using `>>=` and `pure`, but not using `>>=` alone and not using `join` and `pure`.

Comment: It might be worth it to also explain this metaphorically: If you want to edit every value inside of a structure-with-contexts independently with the same action (`fmap`/`(<$>)`), you can accomplish it by editing every value within its context (`extend`/`(<<=)`) and just ignoring the given context (`extract`).